# Long frames in mdframed

Tags: mdframed

I need to use the `mdframed` package with frames extending many pages, e.g. more than 20 pages..
Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \Repeat \prg_replicate:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}
\Repeat{1500}{xxx\\}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

produces (with `pdflatex`) the following error

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 9--10

! Dimension too large.
<argument> \dimexpr \ht \mdf@splitbox@one 
                                          +\dp \mdf@splitbox@one \relax 
l.10 \end{mdframed}
```

What may be the problem here?

Comment: TeX is happy to build boxes whose dimensions exceed `\maxdimen`, as long as you don't try to use those dimensions. The maximum dimension is a bit less than six meters; assuming a text height of 25cm, no more than 23/24 pages can fit.

Comment: I see :) It would be nice if this restriction could be circumvented somehow?

Comment: Just saw @egreg's comment after I posted my answer:-) As I comment below you can actually just ignore it in this case, circumventing it would probably involve re-writing `mdframed` to use the output routine rather than `\vsplit` so that the content is collected on the main vertical list rather than in a box, but that might be tricky....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's actually a tricky error to trap, if a box contains more content than `\maxdimen` that isn't itself an error and you can typeset or split or unbox its contents but any reference to `\ht` of the box , even to test it with `\ifdim\ht\mybox>...` results in an error.

If you add

```
\batchmode
```

You get the document that you wanted....

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work. I wonder, is there any drawbacks of using `\batchmode` ? ( In "TeX by topic" page 232, I find:  "\batchmode TEX fixes errors itself and performs an emergency stop on serious errors
such as missing input files, but no terminal output is generated."

Comment: @HåkonHægland well the drawback is that you don't get informed (on the terminal) of errors, but if you don't make errors that isn't a concern (you can just do it locally for `mdframed` and put it back with `\errorstopmode`)

Comment: Interesting. Do you know a solution.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel My solution was to ping you in chat to come here and fix it:-)

Comment: I thought the maximum height of a vbox can only be `\maxdimen`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel no there is no limit (up to the memory constraints) it's just that you can't _ask_ what the height is if it is too big (basically it is a linked list of nodes and it doesn't calculate the total dimension unless needed so you can collect unbox copy etc just don't access \ht)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel one solution would be to literally do as here, insert `\batchmode` before you do the tests, making sure that you roder them such that the automatic recovery always takes the "large" branch. It is a global setting but you can use the etex `\interactionmode` to find out what the setting was initially and restore it to that after the test. A more complete fix would be to accumulate the body in bits and once you have more than a page worth split it off and ship it out so you never get this big, but that is probably a much bigger change to the code?